# Change the coordinate reference System of a vector data

Tags: python, raster, gdal, qgis

I am working a raster map with crs : (tmerc +lat_0=33 +lon_0=-115.1875 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD27 +units=m +no_defs) and a vector data file in crs: (EPSG:4269,NAD83). I want them in the same crs and crop the small subimages around each point corresponds to the vector data file. Any suggestions to change them to same crs ?

Answer (score 0):

`ogr2ogr` is a powerful vector file conversion program. Reprojecting a shapefile or other vector file is simple. Look at the [docs](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) to see all of the functionality.

```
ogr2ogr output.shp input.shp \\
  -t_srs "merc +lat_0=33 +lon_0=-115.1875 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD27 +units=m +no_defs"
```